# flutter refresh obs list of classes after changing data in it

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, state-management, flutter-getx

I created a list and made it observable by using using getx obs

```
var msgChat = List.filled(1, UserMessagesModel(), growable: true).obs;
```

and if i append or add a new to it, it automatically updates in the UI but my problem is that if i using a single value inside the classes of the list it doesn't get updated until i do it for the second time before it updates

```
socket.on("msg_delivered", (del) {
    OfflineDatabaseManager.instance.updateMsgReadData(del).then((value) {
      uController.msgChat.forEach((el) {
        if (el.msgId == del) {
          print(el.msgId);
          el.isRead = 'true';
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

my listview is wrap using an Obx widget which makes it work but it doesn't updated if a single value in the class of the list is changed please is there a way to like refresh the list or listview and also i can't use `setState(() {});` because an not inside a `Statefulbuilder` but in a class which extends to getx

```
class SocketHandler extends GetxController {}
```

please how do i fix this issue. Thank. Also if you require more explanation then tell me to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use refresh method like this on your observable, after changing the value:

```
msgChat.refresh()
```

if this didn't work, it's probably because you didn't use `Obs` correctly

please share the Obs part if the problem remains so i can help

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't know the .refresh() method for the Rx Obs in Get.